# How to stop ScrollView gliding?

Tags: react-native

In my case, I want to change some states only when the `ScrollView` is not gliding. I would like to know is there any way to implement it like `list.stopGliding()` or `list.stopScrollMomentum()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> `onMomentumScrollBegin`: Called when the momentum scroll starts (scroll which occurs as the ScrollView starts gliding).

and:

> `onMomentumScrollEnd`: Called when the momentum scroll ends (scroll which occurs as the ScrollView glides to a stop).

or you can use:

> `onScrollBeginDrag:` Called when the user begins to drag the scroll view.

and

> `onScrollEndDrag:` Called when the user stops dragging the scroll view and it either stops or begins to glide.

If you want to stop all the momentum, you can use the prop:

```
decelerationRate={0}
```

To read more here's the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview)

Comment: Thanks for reply. The problem is I can only know when it stops. I can't force it to stop at anytime I want.

Comment: So try using the decelerationRate prop with a state, like: `decelerationRate={this.state.deceleration}`, and change the value when you want to, so you can make it stop.
0 to stop, 1 to continue, or something like this.